# How to connect multiple AT28C256/AT93C256/AT24C256/24LC512 EEPROMS to have more space

Tags: atmega, eeprom

I want to have more memory say 1 Mega Byte, But I don't know how to connect multiple EEPROMS either in series or parallel

I would like to use either AT28.... or AT93.... or AT24.... series

Also suggest that, is 4x4 DIP EEPROM is better than 16x16 or 8x8?

It seems 24LC512 provides 512Kb and AT24C1024 provides 1024Kb with 2-Wire Serial, How many of them will make 1 Mega Byte?

Comment: I would have thought that connecting in parallel and using the chip-enable to select which one you want to talk to would be the way to go. Happy to be corrected by more experienced users.

Comment: Is that 1M byte or 1M bit that you want? I presume that AT93C56 is a mistype, and that you mean AT93C256?

Answer (score 1):

The AT28 and AT93 are 2 quite different families of parts.

**The AT93** uses a serial interface known as SPI, and usually comes in an 8 pin package. It is very easy to interface to using almost any microcontroller, and is adequate for most purposes. This part, and the similar 24LC part that uses I2C are very common parts.

**The AT28** uses an 8-bit parallel interface, and comes in a 28-pin package. It is relatively difficult to interface to using a microcontroller, and is normally only used in microprocessor designs which use a full databus. However it is capable of higher read and write speeds. It is not a very common part.

Assuming that you want 1M byte of EEPROM then the AT93C56 is definitely not the part to use. It has just 256 bytes of memory, you will need 4000 chips to give you 1 MB. You need to use a AT25M02 which has 2M bit of memory, so 4 chips will give you 1M byte. These are connected as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTZ5FN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: AT25M02 may not be widely sold, but your answer is useful

Comment: It seems it is an SMD, May I know any DIP version? like AT24C1024